# Contractual clause for wrong deployment

Tags: untagged

Of late, one of my application vendor has been making numerous mistakes or errors in the deployment scripts, ie the deployment scripts fail and the system team (server and database) need to deploy additional times to fix their mistakes. The application and system team are two different vendors. We are in the process of renewing our maintenance contract with the application vendor. I would like to put a clause in the maintenance contract to remind the application team to do their due diligence in ensuring that the deployment script is running properly and to minimise any repeated error. Any sample which i can look at?

Answer (score 1):

It's very unlikely you will find any examples which fit your needs and jurisdiction.  You should talk to a lawyer familiar with these issues in your legal jurisdiction to get something appropriate written.

Answer (score 1):

It would be very difficult to get a vendor to agree to a performance clause without a lot more $$ coming from your side.

Just trying to negotiate it, however, might have the side effect of informing the application vendor that the maintenance vendor is not doing a good job.

I've been blessed by having excellent contract and purchasing support personnel in my career. You may want to talk to these people and let them do the negotiating- this is what they do for a living, and often, they are very good at it.